# Pointless Question Edit?

Tags: discussion, edits

So one of my questions has received an edit.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1244028/revisions

I thought the revision was fairly trivial and wondered why the user even bothered to make the edit. Rather than roll the edit back or re-edit it, thought I'd post here to see if there was anything I've missed.
I've looked at the following post:

[When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

I cannot see why removing 28 characters is really needed? I also like to think I'm polite so the removal of 'Thanks :)' is particularly annoying. Is it considered bad form to put pleasantries like this on questions?

Comment: Yes, those pleasantries are really just noise not related to the question. No one posts here because they aren't looking for help and aren't glad to get it. It is hard to know if you meant to include 'phone' on two rows.

Comment: Don't add greetings and other fluff like that to your posts, it's considered "noise" on SO.

Comment: Oh, and you may want to change the accepted answer on that question.

Comment: Please, check the site [Tour], "thanks" and salutations are noise and always removed when doing substantial edits. . . But I'm really not sure about the removal of the duplicated "Phone"...

Comment: @JayBlanchard When "it is hard to know" if an OP's sample data is correct, the appropriate action is not to unilaterally change it but to post a comment asking for clarification. In this case, since multiple items were duplicated (but had unique IDs), I'd say it was intentional and should not have been edited.

Comment: I'd agree with that @AndrewMedico

Comment: I came to be educated and have been. I want to say thanks but won't ;) The duplicate data was intended at the time but for the purpose of the post I guess it's no longer needed.

Comment: Lots of answers that were posted to that question cannot work as long as the list has "Phone" more than once.  Surely that matters a great deal.  The editor just assumed it was a mistake in the question.  Surely it was.

Comment: @HansPassant And the fact there are two "Health" listings doesn't affect them? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Tikeb The point is to keep things like "thanks" out of the *question* but not off the site entirely - being polite and friendly in *comments* is excellent.

Comment: @Cerbrus I agree with you, don't add that kind of noise, but this post was from 2009 - this thanks has been hanging around for 5 years, it kind of was unnecessary to edit it solely to remove that.

Comment: @bluefeet: Ah, I didn't check the date.

Comment: Even if YOU think "greetings" and "thanks" are "noise", others do not and it is your opinion.  It is my opinion that edits correcting incorrect use of their, they're and there are ok, they are an actual absolute mistake.  Removing greetings and thanks is being a Grammar Nazi at it's worst; it's like changing "this, that and the other thing" to "this, that, and the other thing"; not really necessary and who the frack cares?

Comment: @MichaelGeiser It's not a matter of opinion in this case, that's the community guidelines. It's been discussed before. See the link in the answer bluefeet posted below. Also note the dates in that post. This is not a new development.

Comment: @Kendra  just out of curiosity, where are the community guidelines?  Even if they are in the guidelines, it's still subjective if they are "bad".  I actually saw the dates and the other link, but additional feedback that it seems like an odd practice is good feedback to those that codified their opinions into the community guidelines...

Comment: @MichaelGeiser If you don't agree with the guidelines in that post, then see [this post in the help center.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) To quote one of the headings: _"Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings."_ As for thanks, you thank answerers by accepting and upvoting their answers if they helped you. You do not need to put it in your post. If you don't agree with these guidelines, these comments are not the place to argue it out, and I will not answer further comments on the matter here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As others have said, [greetings and salutations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) on posts are considered noise and typically are removed - so I understand why that was removed.  However, the post is 5 years old and the removal, IMO, was not critical **and** they removed your data from the question - which doesn't seem at all appropriate since it changes your question.

I've rollback the edit because it changed your data and subsequently removed the "Thanks" which should have been the only thing removed from the post.

Comment: +1 I don't think *occasional* removal of "thank you notes" on old posts would be a problem - i.e. if I find a question/answer via search engine and it makes sense I don't usually worry how old it is before removing thanks (also I have more than 2K+ rep so my edits are cheaper since they don't endup in review queue). Explicit digging for all "thanks" to farm some editing rep is not nice - but I think such edits should be rejected as minor anyway.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: But [we don't do that anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor).

Comment: @Deduplicator good point "rejected as too minor" (aka you not going +2 for this edit) is now "reject and improve".